# How Console in New Windows Azure Portal Works?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-management-portal

In the new Windows Azure Portal, how does the "Console" Window works? What really happens behind the scenes? I am curious to know how it works internally.
(I can't find that out for myself since I don't have an Azure account :-( )

http://assets.andrewconnell.com/media/Default/Misc/AzurePortalManager04.png[image: Azure Management Portal, Console Blade]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually made this console as my internship project while at Microsoft. It was made before the xplat-cli was available, but it's still very simple and actually uses the Kudu service. Kudu is the engine behind git/hg deployments, WebJobs, and various other features in Azure Web Sites. More information on Kudu here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/

When your web application is created on azure, Kudu stands up a scm website for your web application with the end point yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net. The console then takes commands that you give it, calls Kudu's [REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API)  using the scm website as the endpoint, and then displays you the output in the console.

Comment: Awesome :-) that's informative. And congratulations, very nice job.. especially as an internship project. I hope you work with Microsoft fulltime now.

Comment: How can we connect to it in mac terminal locally?

Comment: @ParthPatel Connect to your Azure App Services (such as a Web App) using the now supported SSH for linux/mac. For more information: https://aka.ms/linux-ssh

Answer (score 0):

That console looks exacly like the [Azure Cross-Platform Command-Line Interface](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) (xplat-cli) which is based on node.js. I'm not a node.js expert, but a good guees would be, that the browser creates a node.js session und runs the xplat-cli in there.

xplat-cli in turn use the [Service Management API of Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx), which are all REST-based.

You can compare the xplat-cli on your own by installing them from the [Downloads page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/). At the bottom of this page are the download links for Windows, Mac, and Linux.